# SSRS 2008 to PDF export bar code error

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have an issue with exporting the results of an SQL report (SSRS 2008) as a PDF file. I use a bar code in the report. The bar code shows correctly when visualizing the report and it is encoded and can be scanned when exporting as Excel/Word. When exporting as PDF, the text shows *16327567* (for example) instead of a bar code (for 3OF9), or some special characters generated by the SQL encoder on which the bar code font should be applied. I used fonts Code128 and 3OF9 and both had same results.

The issue persists across environments as I've called the report from the report server from different servers. I believe it is related to the SQL version.

Here is what I tried already:

- checked the fonts, they are installable, true type and they show up in the PDF when checking from File Properties
- restarted the reporting server services multiple times
- fonts are installed on all environments (SSRS server, client server, my own local machine)
- for Code128 used an encoder that worked previously and did the charm on SQL 2016 (on another server) and the export as PDF there encoded the bar code
- even restarted all SQL related services

Any ideas, please? I hope I haven't missed any detail. Thank you in advance!

Comment: This is an age old problem that I've had issues with. I can't offer a solution, but right clicking the font file > properties > details and check for "font embeddability" - if it says, restricted - you'll need to try something else, sadly.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159713.aspx

Comment: Hello Jon. I've checked them before, they are installable.